# htaccess RewriteRule not letting me acces REAL directories

Tags: .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force add trainling slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://foo.bar/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Prepent www if not exist in URI
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.foo.bar/$1 [R=301,L]

# If path is not a directory or file then apply RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite for profile view
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

# Rewrite for page view
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ account.php?type=$1&user=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]

# Condition to ignore regular links
RewriteRule ^library/templates/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ library/templates/$1/$2/$3 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite for dynamic page settings
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ account.php?type=$1&user=$2&page=$3&$4=$5 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite for account view
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ account.php?type=$1&user=$2 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite for site default resources location
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/theme/s/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ library/themes/site/$3/$4/$5 [QSA,L]
```

I know this is kinda not the best way to go about this, feels like there is too much redundancy but I'm no expert but its working for me. If anyone can give me advise on how to make this more efficient I would highly appreciate it.

Ok so my problem is that I have a real directory at

```
www.foo.bar/path/to/real/dir
```

and I want to access a file in that directory, but my rewrite rules aren't letting access that directory unless I make a new rewrite rule redirecting my url to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for files symlinks and directories as well (as your first rule):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: let me check it out, i'll report what i find